# Parsing a string to php array

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have this line

> comment=Accept established chain=forward connection-state=established

And I need to parse it to array. Using explode("=") doesn't work as expected. I get:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "comment"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Accept established chain"
  [2]=>
  string(24) "forward connection-state"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "established"
}
```

I tried playing with regex( I suck at it badly). but managed to somehow got to 50%:

```
preg_match_all("/[([a-zA-Z\-]+=]?/", $line, $result)
```

which returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "comment="
    [1]=>
    string(6) "chain="
    [2]=>
    string(17) "connection-state="
  }
}
```

So it's half way. Now I don't know how to get the string after the "=" part for each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to parse your string:

```
([a-z-]+)=(.*?)(?=\s*[a-z-]+=|$)
```

It looks for some number of `a-z` or `-` characters (captured in group 1), followed by an `=` sign, followed by some (minimal, using `?` to make the match lazy) number of characters (captured in group 2) up to either another key followed by `=` or the end of string. In PHP

```
$str = 'comment=Accept established chain=forward connection-state=established';
preg_match_all('/([a-z-]+)=(.*?)(?=[a-z-]+=|$)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output (keys are in `$matches[1]`, values in `$matches[2]`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => comment=Accept established 
            [1] => chain=forward 
            [2] => connection-state=established
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => comment
            [1] => chain
            [2] => connection-state
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Accept established 
            [1] => forward 
            [2] => established
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1lMgL)

Note: if the key values could contain uppercase characters, use the `i` flag on the regex i.e.

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z-]+)=(.*?)(?=\s*[a-z-]+=|$)/i', $str, $matches);
```

Also, if you want to generate a `key => value` array, just use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$values = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [comment] => Accept established
    [chain] => forward
    [connection-state] => established
)
```